# Finding records in TableA that don't exist in Table B in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a multi-million Table A which includes Field1

I have another similar Table B

I have done various queries prior on Table A/Field 1

I'd like to try to isolate those Field1s in TableB I am going to need to run similar queries on

So I'd like to basically extract a list of Field1 from TableB where that Field1 does NOT already exist in TableA so I can start to process those records.

Comment: Try:  SELECT field1 FROM TableB WHERE TableB.field1 NOT IN (SELECT field1 FROM TableA)

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was the same as the above comment and I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest way would be:

```
SELECT b.*, a.id 
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a
ON b.field1 = a.field1
WHERE a.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Left joins create temporary tables. This would not be that fast on a large-scale database, even with good indexing.

Comment: yeah that's right, but I think this is one of this cases where it's inevitable... The other suggested solutions are based on a correlated subquery, that's not very scalable on execution time.

Answer (score 0):

```
select field1 
from tableB 
where not exists (select * from tableA where tableB.field1 = tableA.field1)
```